# How to unbound the functions added by particular script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a WordPress website, I have installed contact-form7 and easy fancybox plugins to create a form pop-up on button click, 
So i needed this code

```
 <a class="fancybox" href="#contact_form_pop">Contact Us</button>
 <h1>helo</h1>
<div class="fancybox-hidden" style="display: none;">

<div id="contact_form_pop">[contact-form-7 id="7" title="Contact form 1"]
</div>
 </div>
```

It works fine on all the website, But on my website when I click the anchor button it also scroll down the window, Finally, I found my theme has a long javascript file which is binding some function with this anchor, That script is binding the function by tag  name (a), The script is very complicated i don't wanna change it, Is there any way that it doesn't bind its function with the `a.fancybox` element. Or can I remove the function bound by this script, And only keep the function bound by the fancy box plugin's script

Does it make any sense? , Let me know if need any clarification

Thanks

### Edit

By google developer tools I found that that theme script is binding this function to the `a.fancybox`

```
...function(){if(location.hostname==this.hostname&&location.pathname.replace(/^\//,"")==this.pathname.replace(/^\//,""))return e.scroll_to(this.hash,!0)})},scroll_to:function(e,n,t){if("#infinite-top-anchor"==e)a=0;else{var s=i(e);if(s.leng...
```

#### Solution

```
...function(){if(location.hostname==this.hostname&&location.pathname.replace(/^\//,"")==this.pathname.replace(/^\//,"") && !this.classList.contains('fancybox'))return e.scroll_to(this.hash,!0)})}.....
```

OR

not needed in my case but we can also prevent the function binding to all it's (a.fancybox) inner elements as well we can use closest (closet('a.fancybox') will work on a.fancybox as well )

```
 ...function(){if(location.hostname==this.hostname&&location.pathname.replace(/^\//,"")==this.pathname.replace(/^\//,"") && !this.closest('a.fancybox'))return e.scroll_to(this.hash,!0)})}.....
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the problem page? It could be scrolling you down the page because you have an element on the page with an id of "#contact_form_pop" but without knowing more it is hard for me to say. See this page for instruction on removing javascript event listeners with JS: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp

Comment: You can only remove specific events if they were added via a named handler, if not then it's trickier. You might be able to just cheat by overwriting the problem function with a new empty function with the same name, but we'd definitely need to see more of the code to be more help.

Comment: @delinear,  JonahAaron   Thanks for your help,  Sorry, I can't share the whole code here,  I think i  have to solve it myself, As it is very difficult for others to help without the code. THanks :)